# Is there a recommended website to get started?

Tags: recipe

I have 5 gallon bucket with sealed top, spigot and an air trap. I'm wondering what I can make. Is there any website that will give me recipes that I can try? I'm itching to make something.

Comment: Depends what you want to make, wine, beer, other fruit wines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"How to Brew" by John Palmer.

http://www.howtobrew.com/

It is also available as a physical book.  Highly recommended!  It is generally regarded as **the** book for getting started these days.

Enjoy the hobby!

Answer (score 3):

The American Homebrewers Association: https://www.homebrewersassociation.org/

Answer (score 3):

There are so many resources on the internet these days:

[BeerRecipies.org](http://beerrecipes.org/)

[Brewtoad](https://www.brewtoad.com/recipe)

[American Home Brewers Association](http://www.homebrewersassociation.org/homebrew-recipes/)

This is the book from CAMRA in the UK that got me started down this long long road about 14 years ago:

[CAMRA Guide to Home Brewing](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/185249137X/)

Also here there are a number of recipes on this site where people have been asking for comment.

If you are looking to design your own recipies in the future here are a few more places for you to look:

[BeerSmith's Blog](http://beersmith.com/blog/2010/01/27/beer-recipe-design/)

[Designing Great Beers - Ray Daniels](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0937381500/)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend: http://brewworld.com.au for tutorials, tips, and cooking directions plus the best products and kits available in the market.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this in the future, you can try [Brewsearch](http://brewsearch.beer)

It has a neat little random recipe button that will give you 3 new recipes to try.